# My Email Strightly goes to gmail spam/just folder ( DKIM,SPF,DMARC is okay )

Tags: spam, spf, gmail, reverse-dns, dkim

( it's not duplicate , its related to rDNS , please don't flag it as duplicate or give me the link of related one )

i have a problem, my emails from my mydomain.com straightly goes to spam folder in gmail, other service providers are okay.

i have setup DKIM , SPF and DMARC and test them with verifier.port25.com and the result are:

SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

i send my emails from WordPress that using (PHPmailer function), I'm suspicious that my rDNS config is wrong, my current value of rDNS is xx.544654-5454.eu and gmail says that the xx.544654-5454.eu not encrypt your message , should i change my rDNS to mydomain.com ?

Answer (score 0):

That sometimes happens when and email provider has blacklisted the IP address for mail spam. To stop this situtation, you need to talk with gmail directly so they unban your ip as it's a legit domain now.

Comment: thanks alex for answering, but i checked my ip with all blacklist services... it's not related to blacklist.